# Is it correct aspnetcore way? Service & Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

so i want to create some service that accesses external API, and i want to cache common requests from the API inside of that service, it depends on 3 other services, but i want to give it its own instance of cache,  MemoryDistributedCache might later be changed for something else

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomeApi, SomeApi>(provider => new SomeApi(
    Configuration.Get<Options>(),
    new MemoryDistributedCache(new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions())),
    provider.GetService<ILogger<SomeApi>>()
    ));
```

now from my Controllers i can access the api via DI, it works nicely but im not sure if its some sort of an anti-pattern or if there are better ways of doing it

i mean the real problem is separating the internal cache, requesting
IDistributedMemory from one service would give me the same object as if i request it from another service, they must be separated

Comment: Why does it need to be a separate cache? Also, just a note: `GetService<T>()` returns null if the service is not found. So if your service really needs the logger, use `GetRequiredService<T>()`.

Comment: lets say one cache is backed by one Database system, second cache is backed by another

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you could use a proxy or decorator pattern for. The basic problem is that you have a service that does some data access, and another service responsible for caching the results of the first service. I realize you're not using a repository *per se*, but nonetheless the CachedRepository pattern should work for your needs. See here:

http://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern
and
http://ardalis.com/building-a-cachedrepository-via-strategy-pattern

You can write your cached implementation such that it takes in the actual SomeApi type in its constructor if you don't need that part of the design to be flexible.